# "'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'" when try to use pip in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I get this error when I try to use pip in virtualenv.It works nice when I deactivate environment. What could be wrong? I use python 2.7 in CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

Could be your version of [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). The web site says "We advise installing virtualenv-1.9 or greater. Prior to version 1.9, the pip included in virtualenv did not not download from PyPI over SSL."

Comment: I've got 1.9.1 version installed on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by installing latest version of pip and recompiling python with SSL support.